# Saving an instance derived from a base class

Tags: java, class, dao, ibatis

I have a base class, Fruit, and an instance of a child class, Apple. How should I go about saving the Apple instance to a database? Would an `insertFruit` method with an `instanceof` check to detect an Apple be considered as good design or not?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good design to have a method in the superclass that checks if the object is an instance of a subclass. What if you want to add Banana later? Will you add another check in insertFruit()?

I think it would be better to go with polymorphism, and override the insertFruit() method in the Apple class.

Comment: You're right. What could be done is to have an override as you say that would save fields specific to a subclass and then call the save method for Fruit for fields in the base class. In the DB this would reflect as a new record for an Apple, it's id then being used in a Fruit entry.